# Create alist (not list) of unevaluated functions in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a list of unevaluated functions in R using alist. I want a "myList" which could be generated by the following:

```
xlist = c("A", "B", "C", ..., "Z")
myList = alist(print(xlist[1]), print(xlist[2]), print(xlist[3]), ..., print(xlist[26]))
```

However the above is only feasible when xlist is short. How can I generate myList using some clever functions? I have tried sapply.

```
tempfun = function(x) alist(print(x))
myList = sapply(xlist, tempfun)
```

But the result of myList only contains print(x), not print(xlist[i]) in the i-th entry.

Comment: `lapply(1:26, function(x) substitute(print(xlist[x]), list(x = x)))` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having quite a bit of trouble understanding this request. Function names would not be quoted. Making a list of functions is quite simple:

```
funclist <- c(mean, sd, median)
X <- exp(1:10)
funclist[1](X)  # you might think that this was a vector, but NOT.
Error: attempt to apply non-function
funclist[[1]]( X )  # Note that funclist[[1]] _is_ a function so "works" with an open-paren
[1] 3484.377
```

The explanation for this minor mystery is that language elements (of which  functions are but one example) obey list processing semantics, so `c(mean, sd, median)` is really no different than `list(mean, sd, median)`.

If you really were starting with "almost real" function names, i.e character values corresponding to an actual (unquoted) R-`name` then just use `get` to push that value through the permeable membrane separating language- and data-objects

```
> a <- c("mean", "median", "sd")
> get(a[2])
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
UseMethod("median")
<bytecode: 0x7fb26bb76708>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

I do admit that the terms "quoted" and the result semantics surrounding the `quote` function are confusing when examined closely. Notice that the "name" of a function is not really surrounded by flanking double quotes, unless one is traveling through hadley-space.